# How can I move all files and folders from root of usb flash drive to a folder by using windows command line?

Tags: windows, cmd, copy

What is the best way to move all files and folders from root of usb flash drive to a folder by using windows command line?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/831588/how-can-i-copy-a-file-from-a-usb-drive-to-a-directory-on-the-hard-drive-in-windo

Comment: Command line of what OS shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Scenario1:**

Need to copy the files from particular directory which is present in pen drive to particular directory which is present in system hard drive

```
source path: F:\aaa\bbb\  (F: is pendrive)
target path: D:\xxx\yyy\
```

**Code1:**

```
copy F:\aaa\bbb\file.name D:\xxx\yyy\
```

---

**Scenario2:**

Need to copy all files from pen drive to particular directory which is present in system hard drive

```
source path: F: (F: is pendrive)
target path: D:\xxx\yyy\
```

**Code2:**

```
copy F:\aaa\bbb\*.* D:\xxx\yyy\
```

Type `copy /?` for more help.

---

**Scenario3:**

Need to copy ALL files AND folders from one drive to another.

```
source path: F: (F: is pendrive)
target path: D:\xxx
```

**Code3:**

```
xcopy /s F:\*.* D:\xxx
```

**Obs.:**

`/s` Copies directories and subdirectories, unless they are empty. If you omit `/s`, `xcopy` works within a single directory.

Read more about `xcopy` parameters at [MSFT Docs](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true).

---

*Credits to [this post.](https://superuser.com/questions/831588/how-can-i-copy-a-file-from-a-usb-drive-to-a-directory-on-the-hard-drive-in-windo) It was previously posted here and then moved to SuperUser.*

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to copy only all files, I want to copy all files and folders